# Find the shortest regex match c#?

Tags: c#, regex

Basically i am making some imaginary numbers calculator and playing around in regex, coming around this issue. The pattern suggests matching all chars between + or -(counting them in), to char 'i'. Basically the imaginary value. The issue is, the regex matches "-2-2" instead of just -2. So how can I match only the shortest possible match, so the value becomes -2?

here is my code:

```
text = "(-2-2i)";
string pattern = @"(?=(\+|\-))(.\*)(?=i)";
Match match = Regex.Match(text, pattern);
value += Convert.ToInt16(match.Value);
```

I googled it and hadn't found much, since I am a regex beginner.

Comment: Use `string pattern = @"[+-]?\d+(?=i)";`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
text = "(-2-2i)";
string pattern = @"(\+|\-)(.+?)i";
Match match = Regex.Match(text, pattern);
value += Convert.ToInt16(match.Groups[1].Value + match.Groups[2].Value);
```

Comment: You don't want to add them 